# why does java-regex \d match underscore? how do I fix this?

Tags: java, regex

I have this pattern to match digits (and digits ONLY). But somehow it is looking like it also matches underscores.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d)*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("_");
    System.out.println(matcher.find());
```

(This prints `true` meaning `_` matches `(\\d)*`)

Is this a bug???? (I understand that underscores are now part of the numeric literals (as of Java 1.7+)

How do I alter my pattern so it'd exclude underscores?

Edit:

From the suggestions below, I've tried this `[^_]*\\d*`(which didn't work, btw)

Comment: See what adding `System.out.println(matcher.group())` to your code outputs...

Answer (score 6):

The `*` means 0 or more times. So `_` matches 0 digits. Use `+` for 1 or more times.

Comment: Ok, say I really one the `*` how do I say "zero ore more digits AND not udnerscores"

Comment: @OneTwoThree Use a character case to negate the underscore. The `Pattern` javadoc explains how. Note that an empty String will also match that though.

Comment: @OneTwoThree As I said, `*` matches 0 or more times. That pattern is found in `_`. 0 times not `_` and 0 times a digit. Do you want a full match or just to find that pattern?

Answer (score 5):

The modifier `*` matches 0 or more instances.

You probably wanted to use `+` in order to ensure that the string contains a digit.

In order to negate a given character, you could make use of negated character classes:

```
[^_]
```

Answer (score 1):

What matches the underscore is the `*`, try this instead:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("_");
System.out.println(matcher.find());
```

Answer (score 0):

See what adding `System.out.println(matcher.group())` to your code outputs. You are only checking the return value of `find`, which returns `true` iff the regex matched, but says nothing about how many characters are being matched. In your case, `(\\d)*` is matching the area between the start of the string and the underscore, an substring of length 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether input string **matches** your pattern, you should use `matches()` instead of `find()`:

```
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

Currently try to **find** "zero or more digits" in input string, but it will be `true` for any string, because string without digits still contains "zero digits".

Comment: Or even better, use `String.matches()`, which is much more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers provided reason why "_" match with your regular expression.
To solve your need, you can try ( zero or more digits)

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(^\\d*$)");


Explanation:

^ is the beginning of string anchor
$ is the end of string anchor
\d is the digit
* is zero-or-more repetition of
```

if you use negate character (for _ ) this case, you might need to add all cases except number. which might not be efficient or proper way.